# R why use <- before pipes

Tags: r

What are the reasons for writing codes like this:

```
equations <- equations %>%
   some_codes_here
```

instead of

```
equations %>%
   some_codes_here
```

Comment: The first version changes `equations` for the next time you use it, the second one doesn't.

Comment: You can also write `equations %>% some_code -> equation` if you find it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the basic pipe `%>%` won't modify the variable before the pipe. There is a different assignment pipe, from the same package magrittr, `%<>%`, that would also modify the variable `equations`.

However it is way less common, and most R users consider writing the assignment arrow separately to be [a good practice](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html)

Answer (score 1):

@Arnaud Feldmann is correct. You use the left-directed arrows for **assignment**. For instance consider the following example:

```r
a <- c(1,2,3)
```

Now this variable `a` is saved to your environment. You now can do further things with it. For example you could print it:

```r
print(a)
> 1 2 3
```

The pipe operator (`%>%`) you are referring to is an addon from the `dplyr` or `magrittr` package. It can be used to **chain** different operations. Consider following example:

```r
a %>%
  strrep(2)
> "11" "22" "33"
```

When you combine those both, you can extract and transform different objects (`lists`, `dataframes`) with a shorter amount of code. When you combine both techniques it would look like:

```r
b <- a %>%
  strrep(2)
```

Whereas `b` now contains the chained command from `a`.